# I am getting an error while deploying artifacts on Tomcat Server

Tags: spring, maven, web, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've started to learn basic web application using IntelliJ/Tomcat. I've created a basic maven project. Added pom file, `web.xml`, `spring-servlet.xml`, `web.xml` and configured tomcat server to host locally.
The artifacts build without an issue but when I run the tomcat (select war file) - I get Artifact deployment error.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Also, A month ago - I was able to deploy artifacts- but for some other project. I've tried everything from clearing cache, maven clean install, anti lock property= true in context.xml. I have no idea why tomcat is not running properly while it worked a few times earlier.

**Tomcat 8.5.39; Intellij Ultimate2020.1.4 JDK=1.8.0_341**

Here are the server logs

```
09-Nov-2022 12:22:21.804 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
09-Nov-2022 16:15:26.768 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09-Nov-2022 16:15:26.628 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Unexpected exception resolving reference
 java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
09-Nov-2022 16:15:22.181 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.setVersion Unknown version string [4.0]. Default version will be used.
09-Nov-2022 16:15:26.611 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
 java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: It looks like you have some database configuration in your application and the connection to the database cannot be established. Make sure DB server is running and accepting the connections at the specified host/port.

Comment: Thank you! it works now. DB Url was incorrect